# How to install python3.5 in ubuntu 18.10 cosmic

Tags: ppa, 18.10, python3

I need an specific version of python in my host.

I know [deadsnakes ppa](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes) but, but cosmic repository branch is not available.

Are there any alternative?

Comment: You might be able to compile it yourself locally rather easily with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Comment: I'm currently using the 18.04 version... I hope everyithing goes ok.

Answer (score 1):

I'd give Miniconda a try, been using it for months and it's awesome. You can install almost any version of Python on virtual envs, without messing with the system itself or the vanilla Python installed on your Ubuntu.

Just download the Miniconda3 sh script installer for Linux and execute it on a terminal, because it will ask some questions like where to install it and so on:
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Comment: I'm not sure miniconda features. Are you using it to use pip install dependencies too?

Comment: @ssoto yes, it works perfectly fine. Just connect to a desired virtual env and running pip will use the pip of that environment. You can also install dependencies through Conda, but not all of them are available through there.